# laravel ajax validation how to make if it's failed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to make if any values are nothing, show error message box.
`if($validator->passes())`is working successfully, but I have troubles in `if its failed`. `console.log(res)`brings nothing. How can I solve this problem? 
i have tried `$errors = $validator->errors();` `$errors =  json_decode($errors);`

Js

```
 $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $writeForm.serialize(),
        error: function(res){
            if (!res.status) {

                console.log(res.message);
                var error = $.parseJSON(res.message);
                     $('div.visitor-form > div.alert').html(error);

            }
        }

    });
```

controller

```
$validator = validator::make($data = Input::all(), mypage::$rules);
if($validator->fails()) {

        $response = array();
        $response['status'] = false;

        $errors = $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray();
        $response['message'] = $errors;

        return response()->json($response);

    }
```

Comment: 김정명: you want to put client side validation or server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$response['errors'] = $validator->errors()->all();

return response()->json($response, 400);
```

The browser needs to know the error status in order to trigger your `error` method in that ajax function. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error

```
 $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $writeForm.serialize(),
        error: function(res){ //by using this method, you're assuming that all the logic here is for error handling.
                console.log(res.status, res.errors);
        }

    });
```

Comment: It brings errors like this : jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8000/comment 400 (Bad Request)send @ jquery.min.js:4ajax @ jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ mypage.js:106dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
mypage.js:112 undefined 400

Comment: and mypage.js:112 is console.log(res.errors, res.status);

Comment: @김정명 that's ok, you're supposed to receive a `400`. Now you have to figure out how to make the HTML for your alert. For instance, you should do a `console.log(res)` and see what's coming back from that response.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, return any HTTP `error` status code to trigger the error callback method of Ajax.

In your case, 400 (bad request) is suited for validation errors.

```
return Response::json($response, 400);
```